# Exclude or test Laravel Service Providers while testing with coverage

Tags: laravel, phpunit, code-coverage

I was required to test a website and also add code coverage to 100%, I have never done that, I know how to test laravel with phpunit using TDD, in that case everything is working fine. Then I installed **xdebug** to allow code coverage
`./vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html reports/`

My reports are almost to 100%, but the reports shows that **BroadcastServiceProvider.php** is not tested, but I am not using anything with that provider, I don't know if in the future I will use it. I tried this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //Broadcast::routes();

        //require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

But the report still shows that file is 0.0% cover with test, How can I exclude it for coverage?

---

Additional question: the **reports** directory should be uploaded to the repository? if doesn't, how are they going to know if the code is 100% cover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check config/app.php - BroadcastServiceProvider is disabled by default - and certainly not tested

Uncomment it in providers array.

---

Btw, 100% coverage <> perfectly tested application

Comment: It is already disabled: // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class, so strange

Comment: Yep :) and if you wish for 100% coverage - enable/uncomment it.

Comment: I got it, I misunderstand you, Now everything is working fine, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The additional question (now as you asked it, not good in the Stackoverflow format, search for it first) has not been answered:

> the reports directory should be uploaded to the repository?

No.

> if doesn't, how are they going to know if the code is 100% cover?

By running the test-suite and gathering the test-coverage - like you do.

This is normally done with a build server (CI job runner, Github action however it is called) and capturing diverse metrics per each commit (incl. coverage data).

You then can preview changes in metric per each change in the repository, prepare your changes and file *done* changes as a single commit (change-set), commonly known as *atomic commit*.

use the commit message to share your understanding as normally the code-changes alone do not capture that.

e.g. if you commit changes "for 100% coverage because I was told so" write that into the commit message so that the context of the change is clear.

in case that is not the culture at work, only do a commit with a single-line on top that is no-saying like: "fix tests".

don't be fooled: what the culture at work is, is what your boss lives. most managers are sociopaths, and if you need to ask on stackoverflow because of your work, keep your mouth shut in professional communication. the less you say/write, the better.

or to answer your question:

> if doesn't, how are they going to know if the code is 100% cover?

try and error. in case they complain, have your 100% report on disk per commit and sign your commits.